# How to scale size of interface without losing quality?

Tags: java, swing, interface, scale

Because I cannot see small letters I set windows display to 150%. All things on my monitor are resized without losing quality. But unfortunately, it doesn't happen with Java Swing interface. Indeed, the Swing interface is scaled, but  it has a wrong quality.

Can somebody help me to solve it?

Comment: What do you mean "losing quality"? The resolution becomes worse?

Comment: Please: a) Link to a screenshot of a simple Swing GUI beside one of the other apps. Crop it down to just those two. b) Provide the code of the Swing GUI. PS: I doubt that providing the code will progress the problem, but on the other hand, there's a (very small) chance it might.

Comment: @daniu I think your suggestion of 'resolution' is correct, but a screenshot would .. "paint a thousand words" as they say.

Comment: The losing quality means the image is scaling without increasing the number of the pixels!

Comment: I cannot post images, I don't have necessary reputation.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what exactly you mean by "quality", but you can set rendering hints with several options, e.g. anti-aliasing:

```
public void paint (graphics g){
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
    RenderingHints rh = new RenderingHints(
             RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING,
             RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    g2.setRenderingHints(rh);
...
}
```

There are several of these hints, you can [find a list here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/advanced/quality.html).